# gensim doc2vec documents not found by id

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

Here is my code for training my doc2vec model

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from FileDocIterator import FileDocIterator

doc_file_name = 'doc_6million.txt'
docs = FileDocIterator(doc_file_name)
print "Fitting started"
model = Doc2Vec(docs, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, negative=20, workers=6, iter=4)
print "Saving model"
model.save("doc2vec_model")
print "model saved"
```

Now lets take a look at `FileDocIterator`

```
import json

from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.models import Phrases

class FileDocIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.phrase = Phrases.load("phrases")

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open(self.fileName):
            jsData = json.loads(line)
            yield TaggedDocument(words=jsData["data"], tags=jsData["id"])
```

Now I do understand that phrases isn't being used in this implementation, but bear with me here, lets take a look at how the data looks like. Here is the first data point

```
{"data":["strategic","and","analytical","technical","program","director","and","innovator","who","inspires","calculated","risk-taking","in","emerging","technologies",",","such","as","cyber","security",",","risk",",","analytics",",","big","data",",","cloud",",","mobility","and","3d","printing",".","known","for","growing","company","profit","through","innovative","thinking","aimed","at","improving","employee","productivity","and","providing","solutions","to","private","industry","and","government","customers",".","recognized","for","invigorating","creative","thinking","and","collaboration","within","large","companies","to","leverage","their","economies","of","scale","to","capture","market","share",".","successful","in","managing","the","risk","and","uncertainty","throughout","the","innovation","lifecycle","by","leveraging","an","innovation","management","framework","to","overcome","barriers",".","track","record","of","producing","results","in","competitive",",","rapidly","changing","environments","where","innovation","and","customer","satisfaction","is","the","business",".","competencies","include",":","innovation","management","cyber",",","risk",",","analytics",",","cloud","computing","and","mobility","technology","development","security","compliance",":","dod/ic","(","nispom",",","icd","503",",","fedramp",")","commercial","(","iso/iec","27002",",","pci","dss",")","relationship","management",":","dod",",","public","sector","and","intelligence","community","change","management","it","security","&","risk","management","(","cissp",")","program",",","product","&","portfolio","management","(","pmp",")","data","analytics","management","(","cchd",")","itil","service",
"management","(","itilv3-expert",")"],
"id":"55c37f730d03382935e12767"}
```

My understanding is that the id, `55c37f730d03382935e12767` should be the id of the document, so doing the following ought to give me back a docVector.

```
model.docvecs["55c37f730d03382935e12767"]
```

Instead, this is what is outputed.

```
>>> model.docvecs["55c37f730d03382935e12767"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 341, in __getitem__
    return self.doctag_syn0[self._int_index(index)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 315, in _int_index
    return self.max_rawint + 1 + self.doctags[index].offset
KeyError: '55c37f730d03382935e12767'
```

Trying to get most similar gives the following back

```
>>> model.docvecs.most_similar("55c37f730d03382935e12767")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 450, in most_similar
    raise KeyError("doc '%s' not in trained set" % doc)
KeyError: "doc '55c37f730d03382935e12767' not in trained set"
```

What I'm trying to understand is how are doc vectors saved and what id's are used. What part of my approach isn't working above?

Now here's something interesting, if I do the following I get back similar doc vectors but they have no meaning to me.

```
>>> model.docvecs.most_similar(str(1))
[(u'8', 0.9000369906425476), (u'3', 0.8878246545791626), (u'7', 0.886141836643219), (u'2', 0.8834314942359924), (u'e', 0.8812381029129028), (u'a', 0.8648831248283386), (u'd', 0.8587037920951843), (u'0', 0.8413013219833374), (u'4', 0.8385311365127563), (u'c', 0.8290119767189026)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TaggedDocument.tags` should be a list of tags, not a string. By providing a string, the library sees it as a list-of-characters, so the single-characters are interpreted as the document-tags. Change your line:

```
            yield TaggedDocument(words=jsData["data"], tags=jsData["id"])
```

...to...

```
            yield TaggedDocument(words=jsData["data"], tags=[jsData["id"]])
```

...and you will likely see the expected results.